# Trigger events that are loaded via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

The issue: when retrieving data from an Ajax request that contains components to be used in jQuery calls. The jQuery isn't working.

Solution: as answered by  Bikash Waiba the reason this happens is because the jQuery functionality needs to know the page has loaded.

Comment: You are using an ID, make sure that the ID doesn't repeat on the same page. Try to use class in your event if that is your case.

Comment: good point! It's part of a while loop so i am churning out a lot of results all containing the same id. I can advise that i was originally using the class as a selector and the issue is still the same.

Comment: You did using function, that's good. But should work with dom event binding as well. https://jsfiddle.net/azmgdqc4/

Comment: Thanks, it works good in your jsfiddle but for some reason I just couldn't get standard event binding to work in my scenario. I'm going to try cleaning it up and trying this way again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing html from a php function is absolutely ok the problem arises if you echo the block dynamically after page load via ajax in such case you can do something like this

```
$(document).on("click",'#likeClick',function(e){
     var id = $('#likeClick').data('value');
   $.ajax({
     url: '../resources/handlers/like.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {id: id},
     cache:false,
     success: function(data) {
       $('#likeNumber').html(data);
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: that is exactly what i am doing, the code being echoed is via ajax. This is really interesting to know and i thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could make it into a function, and have use the `onclick=""` attribute to call the function.

```
<script>
function request(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../resources/handlers/like.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {id: id},
      cache:false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#likeNumber').html(data);
      }
    });
}
</script>
<div class='community-post-like-button' id='likeClick' data-value='test' onclick="request(this.id);">Like Me</div>
```

Comment: You can directly pass the id to function you dont need `var id = $('#likeClick').data('value');`

Comment: works perfectly as a function, thank you for explaining this way works!

Answer (score 1):

If you have several lines you must use a class attribute instead of an id attribute for the case of #likeClick, use the class .community-post-like-button ids should not be repeated in a same HTML document.
Your code would look like this then.

HTML

```
<div class='community-post-like-button' id='likeClick' data-value='{$id}'>Like Me</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.community-post-like-button').click(function(){
         var id = $(this).data('value');
         $.ajax({
         url: '../resources/handlers/like.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {id: id},
         cache:false,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#likeNumber').html(data);
          }
        });
       });
   });
```